# Battery, current and voltage

Tags: voltage

Something I have been meaning to ask when working on my car:

Why is it that we have a 12 volt battery? Why not say 1.5 or 3 volts? Because if current is all that matters, then we could achieve higher current values to power one load (or multiple loads) with lower resistor values, no? Is it that a higher voltage battery can handle more loads for a certain amount of time or or does it have to do with the power rating of the loads we are attempting to run.

My initial guess is that sure we could use a 1.5 volt battery to say run a motor or other multiple loads (with lower resistance) but that battery would be drained fairly quickly in terms of amp hours. Am I thinking right?

PS: I am trying to think of this problem without use of transformer.

Comment: You don't have 1.5V or 3V batteries in a car because a SLA cell has a potential of about 2.1V.

Comment: The lower the voltage, the higher the current for a given power - and power is usually what we need in the end. Higher current means larger wire, heavier-duty switches and connectors, etc.

Comment: Because current isn't all that matters. When power matters, because power=current*voltage, you need less current if you have higher voltage. And that saves money and weight by allowing thinner wires.

Comment: Also you won't use resistors to power the loads, the loads ARE the resistors.

Answer (score 4):

Choosing an adequate power supply requires knowing the electrical characteristics of the target system. Please note the term *power supply* is used instead of *voltage* or *current supply*. Power ist defined as P = U * I. So in theory, for the same power at half the voltage, you need to double the current. So, for a given power requirement, different combinations of voltage and current are possible, but not necessarily feasible.

In practice, most loads are more sophisticated than pure resistive loads, whoch leads to load specific power supply criteria. E.g., semiconductor-based circuits  require a minimum voltage in order to work as intended. On the other hand, they cannot sustain too high voltages without permanent damage. Additionally, high voltages need proper isolation which is typically space-demanding.

Concerning currents, one needs to consider parasitic resistance of any conducting material. High currents require thick cables (which is why power transmission over long distances uses high voltages).

In automotive applications, 12 V is widely used as it's a good tradeoff between the aforementioned drawbacks of too high/low current/voltage.

Comment: I like your points about transistor circuits and their associated voltage requirements. Many people forget about this when considering the load - and as you mentioned, it isn't purely resistive! Solid first answer - welcome to SE.EE!

Answer (score 1):

What really matters is power, i.e. Watts, not current. Current alone is meaningless without knowing the voltage or the load impedance (which are correlated - if you know two of them you can calculate the third). Power is equal to V x I - or, alternatively, proportional to I² (but, again, here you need to also know V or R to get a usable result). But the diameter of the wires needed to transport such power is proportional to I, meaning if you double the wire diameter the power it can transmit is multiplied by 4. Now, you'll want the wire as thin as possible, and also you want the voltage to be as low as possible - for safety reasons, and also for design reasons. The better compromise between the two is the reason why your car has 12V, your house has 120 or 240 volts, and long distance power lines have 10,000s of volts.

Answer (score -2):

I think you may be getting confused a bit.

When you change the "resistors", you are essentially changing the load. Yes, you could add resistors in series or parallel to your load for adjustment, but this is rarely done in practice due to the typical load not being fully resistive, there might be capacitive or inductive properties to the load.

For this sake we can consider a load in your car un-adjustable.

The voltage of a battery does not determine its capacity (Amp-Hours).

Also, current is dependant on voltage. V=I*Z. A battery is a DC voltage source, not a current source. So saying that a 1.5V battery would supply the same current as a 12V battery is incorrect when it's applied to the same load.

Very often electronics will not operate below a threshold voltage. The battery is your car is most likely used for ignition and lights. The lights would not be illuminating if only 1.5V were applied.

Hope this clears the air on a few things, please feel free to ask any more questions. I am open for discussion.
Cheers!